# Are sampling weights necessary in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, weighted-regression, survey-weights

When should I use weights when performing a logistic regression? The weights I'm referring to are sampling weights from a survey? Or should I just use the unweighted data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sampling weights are designed to account for the non-simple random sample nature of your sample. Therefore, they are just as needed in one form of regression as another. Exactly how to do this may be complicated; e.g. in `SAS` there is `PROC SURVEYLOGISTIC` to deal with various sorts of samples. In `R` there is the `survey` package which I think does similar things (but I have not used it).

Comment: Not for any form of regression. Weights in linear regression are necessary only if we think errors are not independent by $X$: ([pdf](https://ojs.ub.uni-konstanz.de/srm/article/view/47)).

Comment: This paper: ([pdf](http://unionstats.gsu.edu/9220/Solon_WhatWeightingFor_JHR_2015.pdf)) adds other reasons why one should weight, that are however related to violations of the standard hypotheses: i.e.heteroskedasticity, endogenous sampling and identifying average partial effects.